# Roots of a polynomial. Rotating the unknown quantity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$, $p\in\mathbb{C}\left[  x\right]  $ and $q\left(
x\right)  =p\left(  ix\right)  $. The following reasoning is false: $p\left(
r\right)  =0$ iff $p\left(  i\left(  -ir\right)  \right)  =0$ iff $q\left(
-ir\right)  =0$; but $q\in\mathbb{C}\left[  x\right]  $ so $q\left(
ir\right)  =0$. This is contradictory since $q\left(  ir\right)  =p\left(
-r\right)  $ however $-r\in\mathbb{R}$ is not necessarily a root of $p$. Where's the blunder?

Comment: Why if $q(-ir)=0$ and $q\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, you deduce $q(ir)=0$? For example $q(x):=x+ir\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, for $r\neq0$, satisfies $q(-ir)=0$, but $q(ir)=2ir\neq0$.

Comment: However complex roots appear in conjugated pairs.

Comment: You are remembering only half of the result. The statement should be: For polynomials with *real coefficients* roots appear in conjugate pairs.